# Does "Branch out of date with Base Branch" cause issues with Merge Queues?

Tags: github-actions

I was aiming to have Merge Queues function, but I was noticing some PR are showing up with Branch out of Date with Base Branch.   If I have checks and a Merge Queue, I figured that it would handle it, but I didn't see anywhere that it would attempt to resolve it.

To me, I think it would, and are waiting to see if it would be a blocker or not.  Right now I have a bunch of various tickets set to merge when ready.  I think that this would be a problem with the flow.

I noticed that in the Settings for my Branch protections it is checked:

```
[x]  Require branches to be up to date before merging
```

Which I think will say "Oh this needs to be up to date before it will auto merge.  I have no problem toggling this off.

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/configuring-pull-request-merges/managing-a-merge-queue

> The merge queue provides the same benefits as the Require branches to be up to date before merging branch protection, but does not require a pull request author to update their pull request branch and wait for status checks to finish before trying to merge.

So the way this is written is that it does this, or at least should do it whether or not the toggle is set.  The toggle is just there for Manual merges outside the realm of the merge queue, such as running tests from within that Branch etc.